# Duplicated definitions in object file with C++ (MVS)

Tags: c++, variables, dll, export, duplicates

I have this structure of files in my DLL project:

```
// common_header.h //////////////////

   extern int  CommonVar = 0;
   extern bool CommonVar2 = false;

   EXPORT_API void ThisFunction();
   EXPORT_API bool ThisOtherFunction();


// library_part1.cpp ////////////////
   #include "common_header.h"

   EXPORT_API void ThisFunction() {
       if (CommonVar2) CommonVar++;
   }

// library_part2.cpp ////////////////
   #include "common_header.h"

   EXPORT_API bool ThisOtherFunction() {
       if (CommonVar>2) return true;
       return false;
   }
```

As I said, I use Microsoft Visual Studio to build this up into a DLL and of course, I get linking errors related to the fact that those variables are found twice in the object files. That's because it creates a .obj for each .cpp, and how each .cpp includes the same header it also exports the variables. You get it. Now, what I wonder is if there's a solution to this so I can keep those 2 variables common for both .CPP, and also extern (I mean, to be able to read them, at least, from applications using the DLL)? And of course, they must be declared only once in the .obj files. Maybe there's some pre-compiler command for that (like `#pragma once` for headers)

Answer (score 0):

I found it. This is the solution:

```
// common_header.h //////////////////

extern EXPORT_API int  CommonVar;
extern EXPORT_API bool CommonVar2;

EXPORT_API void ThisFunction();
EXPORT_API bool ThisOtherFunction();


// library_part1.cpp ////////////////
#include "common_header.h"

EXPORT_API int  CommonVar = 0;
EXPORT_API bool CommonVar2 = false;

EXPORT_API void ThisFunction() {
   if (CommonVar2) CommonVar++;
}

// library_part2.cpp ////////////////
#include "common_header.h"

EXPORT_API bool ThisOtherFunction() {
   if (CommonVar>2) return true;
   return false;
}
```